# How can I create a PKCS12 File using OpenSSL (self signed certs)

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate

I have a bit9 server, and I'm fairly new to the environment, as well as certs.  The area to upload the cert says "**Import Server Certificate From PKCS12 File**"

I'm going to just use a self signed cert (I'm hoping it's ok with that), and I'm running the below command to do so.

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout bit9.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

Is that what I should have done, and if so, how do I get this to a PKCS12 File?

I've been looking around, and found the below command:

**Convert a PEM certificate file and a private key to PKCS#12**

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out <certificate.pfx> -inkey <privateKey.key> -in <certificate.crt> -certfile <CACert.crt>
```

Since I only have a pem file...I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found steps that led to the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141215/creating-a-p12-file).

Since the answer is spread out across the question, and the answer, I'll just put exactly what I did below.

**Create the key and cert** (-nodes creates without password, means no DES encryption [thanks to jewbix.cube for correction])

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout myKey.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes
```

**Create pkcs12 file**

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out keyStore.p12 -inkey myKey.pem -in cert.pem
```

Comment: I think `-nodes` means "no DES". as in no DES encryption.

Comment: the -nodes is deprecated, use -noenc instead